# What do Sylow $p$-subgroups of a dihedral group $D_{2n}$ look like when $p$ is an odd prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

**Question** Show that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is cyclic and normal when $p$ is an odd prime.
$$
D_{2n}:=\left\{ \langle x,y\rangle|x^{n}=1,y^2=1,xy=yx^{-1}=yx^{n-1} \right\} .
$$

---

**My thought**

Assume that $x^i y\in S$ where $S$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup,
$$
\left( x^iy \right) ^2=x^iy(x^iy)=x^iy(yx^{n-i})=x^i(yy)x^{n-i}=x^ix^{n-i}=1,
$$

implying $\text{order}(x^i y)=2$($i=0,1,\cdots,n-1$), so it can't be a member of $S$ as $|S|=p^r$ is odd, contradiction! Then we know that $S$ is a subgroup of $\langle x\rangle$, cyclic and normal indeed.

However, this deduction has nothing to do with the *prime* property of $p$, only using the fact that $p$ is odd. Therefore, I wonder if there is anything wrong with the idea or it is actually the case. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `$\langle x\rangle$` for $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for your advice! I've edited it.

Comment: I've changed the definition of $D_{2n}$ to the dihedral group of order $2n$ instead of a dihedral group with order $4n$. This change is not crucial w.r.t. what is discussed here, just to fit the convention of denotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument is correct! Indeed, any odd order subgroup of a dihedral group is both cyclic and normal, and this follows from the argument you suggest.

(If you think about the dihedral group geometrically, then half of the group consists of rotations generating a cyclic group, and the other half consists of reflections which all have order two --- this is just another way of saying what you computed geometrically)

Comment: You've offered a nice geometric explanation! Thank you very much for contribution^_^